# How to filter datetime field by date?

Tags: python, django

I have model:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    contract_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Field contract_date stored in db in UTC timezone. I need select all accounts where contract_date__date == date. But date stored in MSK timezone (+3). For example:

```
Account.objects.create(contract_date='2010-01-01 21:00:00')
Account.objects.filter(contract_date__date=date(2010, 1, 2)).all()
```

The query return a empty list.

Comment: Then you need to first convert your MSK datetime to a UTC datetime. Because as you said, the dates in your database are stored (and retrieved by django) as timezone aware and in UTC, assuming you have `settings.USE_TZ = True`.

Comment: I'm filtering by date. Not by datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enabled timezones (`USE_TZ = True` in your settings), then django will make sure that all datetimes are saved in the UTC timezone and retrieved in the UTC timezone.

When displaying them, it will use the current timezone (`settings.TIME_ZONE` or another one if you activate it) to display them in the appropriate timezone. When receiving input from forms, it will convert them to UTC.

Also note that a `date` (2019-01-02) cannot be timezone aware, only a `datetime` can, since without the time, time zones don't make sense.

So in your case, you need to tell Django that you want to filter with the date in MKS timezone. You can use `Trunc` for that:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Trunc
from django.db.models import DateTimeField
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

mks_filter_day = pytz.timezone("Europe/Moscow").localize(datetime(2010, 1, 2))
Account.objects.exclude(contract_date__isnull=True).annotate(
    mks_day=Trunc('contract_date', 'day', output_field=DateTimeField(), tzinfo=pytz.timezone("Europe/Moscow")))\
    .filter(mks_day=mks_filter_day)
# or in Django 1.11 the above doesn't work due to a bug
Account.objects.exclude(contract_date__isnull=True).annotate(
    mks_day=Trunc('contract_date', 'day', output_field=DateTimeField(), tzinfo=pytz.timezone("Europe/Moscow")))\
    .filter(mks_day__contains=datetime.date(2010, 1, 2))
```

This tells the database to convert the datetime to MKS and truncates the day before comparing to the reference date. I make sure `contract_date` isn't null otherwise you get an error.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My solution less elegant: convert msk_date to msk_datetime to utc_datetime (2010-01-01 21:00:00)
```Account.objects.filter(contract_date__range=(utc_datetime, utc_datetime + timedelta(day=1))).all()```

Comment: Not necessarily less elegant. As easy as understand for the person reading the code than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are querying using a date without time... use datetime instead:

`datetime(2010,1,2,21,0,0)`

Comment: I have just date for filtering.